# error: Type 'int[]' of field is not supported | how to add integer list to Realm?

Tags: java, android, list, int, realm

I'm creating Realm Object with Realm Database. I want to declare List `integer` to my object. This is my class:

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String name;
private String image;
private String thumbnail;
private String message;
private int[] genre;
private int[] method;
```

When i compile it, i get error at

```
Error:(12, 8) error: Type 'int[]' of field 'genre' is not supported
```

What to do with this? I tried with `List<Integer>` but no luck.

Then i realized that `Integer` object doesn't extends `RealmObject` so I cannot use it.

Any idea will help. Thanks.

Comment: You could try use `RealmList<Integer>` to store lists of numbers.

Comment: @nbokmans it doesn't work. Reason i told at the end of the question. Then i realized that Integer object doesn't extends RealmObject so I cannot use it.

Comment: you cant make array of int[] without initialising it..

Comment: It is not supported yet. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575. A work-around is described below

Comment: @IntelliJShivam indeed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What to do with this? I tried with List but no luck. Then i
>   realized that Integer object doesn't extends RealmObject so I cannot
>   use it.

Well, you can use the [RealmList](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html) for this purpose :

```
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String name;
private String image;
private String thumbnail;
private String message;
private RealmList<RealmInt> genre;
private RealmList<RealmInt> method;
```

**RealmInt.java**

```
public class RealmInt extends RealmObject {
    private int val;

    public RealmInt() {
    }

    public RealmInt(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

And this is how you'd add elements to the `RealmList`:

```
RealmList<RealmInt> list = new RealmList<RealmInt>();
in.beginArray();
while (in.hasNext()) {
    list.add(new RealmInt(in.nextInt()));
}
```

And then you can call the setter of the main `RealmObject` class and pass the `list`.

[ [SOURCE](https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/1a97377df0c49cd4fca9) ]

Answer (score 2):

People always recommend `RealmList<RealmInt>` and `RealmList<RealmString>` but it comes with a bunch of issues that people don't really realize until they run into them.

Instead, you have two proper options:

1.) flatten the int list into a String, for example store the list as a JSON list

```
 private String genres;

 genres = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
```

2.) create a class that represents your Genre

```
public class Genre extends RealmObject {
    private int genre;

    private Song song;

    @Index
    private int songId;
}
```

And on the other side

```
public class Song extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String image;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String message;
    private RealmList<Genre> genre;
    private RealmList<Method> method;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it if I have problem with the accepted answer.